# Missing Widgets in GNU radio companion (GRC)

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I have started using GNU radio and was following this [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N9SLAnGlGQs) series to get familiar with GRC.

While following along with the tutorials I noticed that I am missing many of the GUI widgets that the tutor was using, for example, the variable slider widget.

I realise that the blocks ultimately translate to some python code, and we could create our own widgets, but the issue is with missing default widgets.

It may be relevant to state here that the software was installed using the synaptic package manager following the instructions [given here.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13zCymh0GmYrRRiDOwv12rt1mylSADyRW/view?usp=sharing)

Is there a fix for this? Maybe some more packages available on Synaptic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your linked tutorial, I believe that wx widgets are used. These are deprecated and you should swap to a Qt gui top_block. To get the slider he used, you may stick to a WX GUI Slider or use a QT GUI Range block, depending on whether your flowgraph is in wx or qt